# Unexpected identifier when passing object to function

Tags: javascript

When im trying to pass object to function, i get "Uncaught syntaxError: Unexpected Identifier".

Code looks like this:

```
myLibrary = [{author: "J.K.Rowling",
    title: "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone",
    numberOfPages: 223,
    read: true
}];

function displayBooksTable () {
    let table = document.getElementById("books-list");
    if(myLibrary.length === 0) {
        table.textContent = '';
        return;
    }
    table.textContent = '';
    myLibrary.forEach((book, index) => {
        let row = table.insertRow(-1);
        let title = row.insertCell(0);
        let author = row.insertCell(1);
        let pages = row.insertCell(2);
        let read = row.insertCell(3);
        let del = row.insertCell(4);
        title.innerHTML = book.title;
        author.innerHTML = book.author;
        pages.innerHTML = book.numberOfPages;
        read.innerHTML = '<button id="read-button" onclick="updateReadButton('+book+')">read</button>'
        del.innerHTML = '<button id="del-button" onclick="deleteButton('+index+')">Delete</button>'
    })
    console.table(myLibrary);
}

const updateReadButton = (book) => {
    book.read = !book.read;
    displayBooksTable();
}
```

Issue is with this:

```
read.innerHTML = '<button id="read-button" onclick="updateReadButton('+book+')">read</button>'
```

and

```
const updateReadButton = (book) => {
    book.read = !book.read;
    displayBooksTable();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can i pass book object to function from forEach loop?

Answer (score 4):

The `book` is an object, but you're turning it into a string when inserting it into HTML markup here:

```
onclick="updateReadButton('+book+')"
```

resulting in problems.

Best to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) entirely - they have problems with quote escaping *and* a crazy scope chain. Add the event listener to the element using `addEventListener`.

```
read.innerHTML = '<button>read</button>';
del.innerHTML = '<button>Delete</button>';
read.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => updateReadButton(book));
del.children[0].addEventListener('click', () => deleteButton(index));
```

Comment: Okay, that worked, im really thankful. However did not understand why previous concatenating didn't work. Delete button worked fine, and it was declared the same way.